# do an action after click on notification flutter?

Tags: flutter, notifications, stream, flutter-local-notification

hello am trying to navigate to a second screen after clicking on notification using flutter_local_notifications
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications

```
final BehaviorSubject<String?> selectNotificationSubject =
      BehaviorSubject<String?>();
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  void initializeNotifcations() async {
    var initialzationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initialzationSettings,
        onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse:
            (NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
      selectNotificationSubject.add(notificationResponse.payload);
    });

    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()!
        .requestPermission();
  }

  void configureDidReceiveLocalNotificationSubject() {
    print('test01');
    selectNotificationSubject.stream.listen((String? payload) async {
      print('test02');
    });
  }
```

not listining to the stream if you got an example of how to make it with the best practice it will help

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal, ialyzaafan Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await initNotification();

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler;
  ...
}



    Future initNotification() async {
  var initializationSettingsAndroid =
  new AndroidInitializationSettings("@drawable/kin_removebg");
  var initializationSettingsIOS = new IOSInitializationSettings(
      requestAlertPermission: false,
      requestBadgePermission: false,
      requestSoundPermission: false,
      onDidReceiveLocalNotification:
          (int? id, String? title, String? body, String? payload) async {});

  var initializationSettings = new InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);

  final NotificationAppLaunchDetails? notificationAppLaunchDetails =
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
  final didNotificationLaunchApp =
      notificationAppLaunchDetails?.didNotificationLaunchApp ?? false;

  if (didNotificationLaunchApp) {
    var payload = notificationAppLaunchDetails!.payload;
    onSelectNotification(payload);
  } else {
     await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
initializationSettings,
onDidReceiveNotificationResponse:onSelectNotification,
onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse:      onSelectNotification,
  }
}

onSelectNotification(NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {

  var payloadData = jsonDecode(notificationResponse.payload);
  print("payload $payload");
  if(payloadData["type"]=="something" && payloadData["id"]!="something"){
    Navigator.of(navigatorKey.currentContext!).push(
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) =>
                SomethingScreen(id: payloadData["id"],)));
  }


}
```

Comment: the onSelectNotification is deprecated

Comment: could you please explain your code?

Answer (score 0):

```dart
flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
  .getNotificationAppLaunchDetails()
  .then((value) async {
    if (!value.didNotificationLaunchApp || value.payload == null) return;
    // do something.
  }
}
```

Comment: Ad more details please

Answer (score 0):

look for the example in the repo for the **in-app** navigation:
https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/blob/033aea63808f4aa5fa817a258d1fdc9e9cd852f1/flutter_local_notifications/example/lib/main.dart#L180C2-L196C5

```dart
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
    initializationSettings,
    onDidReceiveNotificationResponse:
        (NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
      switch (notificationResponse.notificationResponseType) {
        case NotificationResponseType.selectedNotification:
          // On select notification
          break;
        case NotificationResponseType.selectedNotificationAction:
          // Perhaps this section is for custom action with notification
          break;
      }
    },
    onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: notificationTapBackground,
  );
```

If you are using FirebaseMessaging and want to navigate to the app **in background**, you can see the docs here

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive#handling_interaction

Then you can do the navigation logic inside that function. Here I use [global key](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html) to retrieve the current build context

```dart
  static void listenForMesssage() {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(_onMessageOpenedApp);
  }

  static void _onMessageOpenedApp(RemoteMessage event) {
    NotificationService.onMessageOpenedApp(event);
  }

class NotificationService {
...
  static void onMessageOpenedApp(RemoteMessage message) {
    RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
    AndroidNotification? androidNotification = message.notification?.android;
    AppleNotification? appleNotification = message.notification?.apple;

    if (notification == null) return;

    NavigatorState? currentState = navigatorKey.currentState;

    if (androidNotification != null || appleNotification != null) {
      showDialog(
        context: currentState!.context,
        builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
          title: Text(notification.title ?? 'No Title'),
          content: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(notification.body ?? 'No body'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

}

// main.dart
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

void main() async {
  await FirebaseHelper.setupFirebase();
  await NotificationService.initializeNotification();
  runApp(
    const ProviderScope(
      child: App(),
    ),
  );
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return baseProvider.MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        baseProvider.ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => AuthProvider(),
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: const WelcomeScreen(),
        title: "FlutterPhoneAuth",
        navigatorKey: navigatorKey, // Remember to pass the navigator key here
      ),
    );
  }
}
```