# Display FCM in dialog Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, dialog

if the user press on FCM notification, I want to open the app and display dialog containing the FCM content.

now it appears only if the app is open, but if the app is closed I get the notification, when I press it, the app opens but I don't have the dialog.

the app screen sequence main.dart --> loading_screen.dart --> home_screen.dart

What I came to :

main.dart code

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(DPCG());
}

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}

class DPCG extends StatefulWidget {
  static void setLocale(BuildContext context, Locale locale) {
    _DPCGState state =
        context.findRootAncestorStateOfType<_DPCGState>();
    state.setLocale(locale);
  }

  @override
  _DPCGState createState() => _DPCGState();
}

class _DPCGState extends State<DPCG> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);
    return MaterialApp(
      home: LoadingScreen(),
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
        //scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color(0xffd4d4ce),
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          color: Color(0xffd88820),
        ),
        //primaryColor: Colors.black
      ),
      onGenerateRoute: CustomRouter.allRoutes,
      initialRoute: homeRoute,
    );
  }
}
```

no edit in loading_screen.dart

home_screen.dart code

```
class MainHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainHomeState createState() => _MainHomeState();
}

class _MainHomeState extends State<MainHome> {
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    
    _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission();
    _firebaseMessaging.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
      if (notification != null && mounted) {
        print(notification);
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
            title: Text(notification.title ?? "Notification"),
            content: Text(notification.body ?? "Empty body"),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                child: Text("OK"),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: SafeArea(child: Container()),
          )
   }
}
```

**Can someone tell me what I am missing?**

Comment: please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74005059/do-an-action-after-click-on-notification-flutter), may help you

Answer (score 0):

The below code will work for you.

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance
          .getInitialMessage()
          .then((RemoteMessage message) {
      print("FirebaseMessaging.getInitialMessage $message");
   });
```

---

**Updated Code**

---

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  
  //This will listen if app is opened by notification message
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage 
    message) {
        .....
        //Display your dialog
      });
      
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
```

Comment: where to add it? main or home? could explain more.

Comment: Add this in your main screen

Comment: sorry I'm lost, I don't know where it should be added, could you help

Comment: is it possible on main while it doesnt have context to use `showDialog`

Comment: no, it's not possible. so, what you can do is store message in variable and in the initstate of loading screen you can check is that variable have message? and if it have message then display dialog box

Comment: I have tried but it didn't work for me, I would be grateful if you help more, Thanks